# Google analytics and Data Studio: How to show a time series of Year over Year percentage growth

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

On spreadsheets, I have a monthly reporting sheet by various Google Analytics channels (organic, direct, mobile, desktop etc). For each channel, I have another column that automatically calculates the percentage of growth Y-o-Y EX: (A12-A1)/A1. These percentages are then used in a graph to show the trend. So far I haven't found any method of doing this in Data Studio. I presume that calculated fields would be the way but can't figure it out.

For a better understanding of the situation, here is a sample data with attached graph done in Google spreadsheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HyrKb1RysZNXWxFo-W3DZ2EbrKBVmwt5Jvag3_4TJ3A/edit#gid=883733931

Answer (score 0):

Blending data together should do.

Blend the same fields choosing in the date range previous and last year, let's say your metric is pageviews you'll end up with two (2018 and 2019) pageview, in this way you will be able to apply that calculation (not too sure about that A1, perhaps is a typo and should be A11).

Example:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question with a data sample to clarify the case

Comment: That does not change the way you'll need to do this, once you have 2018/19 metric values and apply the % change formula to them you'll be able to just show the percentage instead of a combo chart divided by whatever works best, month/week/day. Try what I've mentioned above, if you'll need further assistance I will be happy to help.

Comment: I have done the blend and is exactly as in your image. Do you have also a graph output and its configuration? Thanks!